# yocto embedded-linux system recovery

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto-project

I work with Yocto Poky 1.7.3 on an imx6DL and i'm trying to implement a system recovery. I can boot system both from NAND and from SD card, but the "main" system resides on NAND. In case of corruption my idea was to boot the system from SD and then overwrite the File System on the NAND with the one located on the SD. The SD card has 2 partitions, one for the boot and one that contains the File System (rootfs.ubifs).

What i tried was:

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt
dd if=/mnt/rootfs.ubifs of=/dev/mtd3 bs=4096
```

but when i rebbot my system i obtain a very long sequence (692 times exactly) of the following errors:

```
UBI error: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 64 bytes from PEB 691:0, read 64 bytes
UBI error: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 4096 bytes from PEB 691:4096, read 4096 bytes
```

and at the end:

```
UBI error: vtbl_check: bad CRC at record 15: 0xd2799447, not 0xf116c36b
Volume table record 15 dump:
    reserved_pebs   0
    alignment       0
    data_pad        0
    vol_type        0
    upd_marker      0
    name_len        0
    name            NULL
UBI error: vtbl_check: bad CRC at record 15: 0xd2799447, not 0xf116c36b
Volume table record 15 dump:
    reserved_pebs   0
    alignment       0
    data_pad        0
    vol_type        0
    upd_marker      0
    name_len        0
    name            NULL
UBI error: process_lvol: both volume tables are corrupted
UBI error: ubi_attach_mtd_dev: failed to attach mtd3, error -22
UBI error: ubi_init: cannot attach mtd3
UBIFS error (pid 1): ubifs_mount: cannot open "ubi0:rootfs", error -19
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU1: stopping
CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 3.10.17imx6dl-ilux-00.00.007 #1
[<80013974>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xec) from [<80011594>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<80011594>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14) from [<80012ba0>] (handle_IPI+0x108/0x118)
[<80012ba0>] (handle_IPI+0x108/0x118) from [<80008558>] (gic_handle_irq+0x58/0x5c)
[<80008558>] (gic_handle_irq+0x58/0x5c) from [<8000dd00>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70)
Exception stack(0xa8097f50 to 0xa8097f98)
7f40:                                     a8097f98 3b9aca00 60217e3e 00000002
7f60: 80874114 808740c8 81136130 00000001 5ecee2a6 00000002 a8096000 00000000
7f80: 00000017 a8097f98 00000009 80428f64 00000113 ffffffff
[<8000dd00>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x70) from [<80428f64>] (cpuidle_enter_state+0x54/0xe4)
[<80428f64>] (cpuidle_enter_state+0x54/0xe4) from [<804290b0>] (cpuidle_idle_call+0xbc/0x154)
[<804290b0>] (cpuidle_idle_call+0xbc/0x154) from [<8000ece4>] (arch_cpu_idle+0x10/0x54)
[<8000ece4>] (arch_cpu_idle+0x10/0x54) from [<80059788>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x100/0x14c)
[<80059788>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x100/0x14c) from [<105ff564>] (0x105ff564)
```

Is there any instructions to substitute the file system correctly?

Thanks

Comment: afaik ubi and ubifs rely on raw flash. without FTL, without error correction. they expect errors and how to handle them. [MTD Big red note](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_rednote) . So writing to a raw flash device, with expected errors, without  consideration for errors (with dd, instead of ubi / ubifs) should give well ... random errors

Comment: the person there looked he knew what he was doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130717/copy-ubifs-partition-to-nand-device (but I didn't get all of it, would require reading ubi's doc...)